# Http request in forEach function. Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

Having problem with using forEach function with http requests.

I have a `_watchlistElements` variable, which holds following data:

`[{"xid":"DP_049908","name":"t10"},{"xid":"DP_928829","name":"t13"},{"xid":"DP_588690","name":"t14"},{"xid":"DP_891890","name":"t16"},{"xid":"DP_693259","name":"t17"}]`

Now, Im making a function which will download data from server for each of these `xid` elements:

```
private download() {
  this._watchlistElements.forEach(v => 
  this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getValue/' + v.xid)
  .subscribe(res => this._values = res.json()));
}
```

It has to download data as object for every `v.xid` value and store it inside the `_values` variable.

`private _values: Array<WatchlistComponent> = [];`

But somehow, angular returns an error with `v.xid` element. It doesn't see that variable. But it's kinda strange, because when I do it just in console, I mean: store that json inside a variable and use forEach function on this `v.xid` elements, everything works well.

> ERROR in [default] C:\Users\src\app\appBody\watchlist\watchl
>   ist.component.ts:51:115
>   Property 'xid' does not exist on type 'WatchlistComponent'.

**The `xid` exists... but inside the `_watchlistElements` which downloads the data asynchonously...**

I'm not 100% sure this method is right, but if you have any ideas how to fix it, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you print out the _values array?

The error above is a type error. What does the WatchlistComponent interface look like? Does it include an `xid` property?

You can get around the type error by overriding the type like...

```
private download() {
  this._watchlistElements.forEach((v as any) => 
  this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getValue/' + v.xid)
  .subscribe(res => this._values = res.json()));
}
```

As far as helping you structure your code better. If you want to combine the result of many Observables, I would use something like forkJoin.

```
private download():void {
  //create an array of Observables
  let el$ = _watchlistElements.map(el => {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getValue/' + el.xid)
             .map(res: Response => <any>res.json());
  });

  //subscribe to all, and store the data, el$ is an array of Observables
  Observable.forkJoin(el$).subscribe( data => {
    this._values = data; //data will be structured as [res[0], res[1], ...]
  });
}
```

HERE is a Plunker with the above method working. https://plnkr.co/edit/woXUIDa0gc55WJPOZMKh?p=preview

Related: [angular2 rxjs observable forkjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048860/angular2-rxjs-observable-forkjoin)

Comment: If I fix my code as you wrote, I'm getting 4 errors. `=` expected, can't find name `as`, `,` expected and `xid` does not exist on WatchlistComponent. What do you mean by printing `_values` array? Do you mean `console.log`? I don't have any interfaces inside the WatchlistComponent.

Comment: yes, `console.log(this._values)` ; Is line 51 of watchlist.component.ts `this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getValue/' + v.xid)` ?

Comment: I bet `console.log` won't work because of asynchronous request. And about your question, yes, it looks like you have written.

Comment: This stuff which you have written as edit, is kinda madness and it doesn't work :(

Comment: @H.Doe I added a Plunker to illustrate the method.