# Multiple POST Requests using forEach Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, foreach, http-post, rxjs

So I am trying to do a POST request in Angular from an array. Basically, when a user selects multiple items in a list they can "unlock" each item. So the issue I am running into is how to do a POST with a forEach. I was able to do a POST with a forLoop but the issue is that when it does one POST it does not do the other one. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong or if there is a better solution to this problem?

Here are the other Stack questions I looked through to find a possible solution:

[Http request in forEach function. Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062395/http-request-in-foreach-function-angular2)

[Angular http post on loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224473/angular-http-post-on-loops)

[Chaining http calls in angular 2 in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035184/chaining-http-calls-in-angular-2-in-a-for-loop)

component.ts

```
locked: Array<any> = [];
// Unlock
  unlock() {
    let observer = {
      next(data) {
        data => console.log(data)
      },
      error(error) {
        return new Error('Post Error');
      },
      complete() {
        console.log("Completed");
        // window.location.reload();
      }
    }
    // On unlock send lock data to Service for POST
    this.http.postUnlock(this.unlocked).subscribe(observer);
  }
```

service.ts

```
// POST to UNLOCK RESOURCES
  postUnlock(locked) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append( 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    locked.forEach((lock) => {
      let newBody = JSON.stringify(lock);
      let auth = lock.AuthID;
      let form = lock.FormName;
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: 'post', body: newBody });
      let newUrl = this.url + `?authid=${auth}&formname=${form}`;
      // POST to URL
      return this.http.post(newUrl, options).map(res => res.json());
    });
  }
```

Is it something that has to do with the Observable or is this something that can be handled with Promises?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To be sur, you have called your service 'http' in your component?

Comment: @Wandrille yes I have added the service in my component and imported it from the file

I do get an error Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void' when I use the forEach, however, it does not produce this error with the forLoop

Comment: Replace `locked.forEach` by `return locked.map` ;)

Comment: @Maxime
So you're saying to do this?

```return locked.map((lock) => {
      let newBody = JSON.stringify(lock);
      let auth = lock.AuthID;
      let form = lock.FormName;
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: 'post', body: newBody });
      let newUrl = this.url + `?authid=${auth}&formname=${form}`;
      // POST to URL
      return this.http.post(newUrl, options).map(res => res.json());
    });```

Comment: @Maxime
after changing to `return locked.map` I now have this error:
TypeError: this.http.postUnlock(...).subscribe is not a function, coming from the component.ts file

Comment: I suspect you want `forkJoin` and not `map` or `forEach`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is a mix between what you looked for ([Http request in forEach function. Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062395/http-request-in-foreach-function-angular2)) and your code.

you cannot return a value from a for each it will exits the function ([What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function/34653650))

hope it helps

```
postUnlock(locked){
  //create an array of Observables
  let allQueries = locked.map(lock => {
    let newBody = JSON.stringify(lock);
    let auth = lock.AuthID;
    let form = lock.FormName;
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: 'post', body: newBody });
    let newUrl = this.url + `?authid=${auth}&formname=${form}`;
    // POST to URL
    return this.http.post(newUrl, options).map(res => res.json());
  });

  //return a new observable that will emit all the http results
  return Observable.forkJoin(allQueries)
}
```

Comment: Yes, there are a number of ways to listen to multiple observables.  `forkJoin` sounds like what you want.  It will wait for all of them to complete and then emit an array of values which correspond to the **last** item emitted by each observable.  It is good when you are dealing with *promise-like* observables (e.g. `Http`) which emit once and then complete.  If you want to handle each item as it comes in you can use `merge` and if your observables emit multiple times there are ways to deal with combining each set of emissions (e.g. `zip` or `combineLatest`).