# Handler exception in a forkjoing with Ionic 2 and Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic2

Is it possible to handle errors separately using *forkjoin*? I need to call multiple requests at the same time, displaying a loading on the screen while the requests are called. If an error occurs in some request, and another success, I need to display the request successfully on the screen, and the error message to the other.

Meu código no Page.ts:

```
getData(){
   this.loadingService.showLoader("Loading, please wait");

   Observable.forkJoin([
      this.issuesService.getIssues(),
      this.categoryService.getCaretories()
    ]).subscribe(
      (response) => {

        let issues = JSON.parse((response[0] as any)._body);
        let categories = JSON.parse((response[1] as any)._body);

        //do something with issues and categories

      }, (error) => {
        console.log(`Backend returned error was: ${error}`);
        this.closeLoading(refresher);
        this.showContent = false;
      }, () => {
        console.log('complete all request');
        this.closeLoading(refresher);
      });
  }
}
```

If an error occurs in the *Issues* request, and in the *Category* request, return success. I need to display on the screen how to successfully *categories*, and display an error message for *Issues*.

Currently, when an error occurs, the error message is displayed for all requests.

Comment: you mean display error for each request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 rxjs observable forkjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048860/angular2-rxjs-observable-forkjoin)

Comment: @SurajRao Not really a dupe since it doesn't explain how errors should be distinguished from real values. But related, yes.

Comment: @estus both questions ask for the same thing. If you are talking about the _answers_... I suppose you can add your additional info here or in the dupe target.

Comment: @SurajRao but the duplicate question don't have 'answers'. And I see the duplicate before, and I tried to solve it as they suggested, but it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

RxJS `forkJoin` works similarly to `Promise.all`. If one of the sources throws an error, the resulting source also throws. If it shouldn't throw, the error should be caught in a source where it is thrown:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.issuesService.getIssues().catch(err => Observable.of(err)),
  this.categoryService.getCaretories().catch(err => Observable.of(err))
)
```

Then errors can be handled like regular values:

```
  .subscribe(([issuesRes, categoriesRes]) => {
    if (issuesRes instanceof Error) ...
    else ...
  });
```