# Angular - RxJs ForkJoin How To Continue Multiple Requests Even After A Error

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join

I am querying a single API endpoint multiple times except with different parameters. For what ever reason some of these requests may fail and return a 500 error. If they do i still want the other requests to carry on and return me the data of all the successfull requests.

```
let terms = [];
terms.push(this.category.category);
terms = terms.concat(this.category.interests.map((x) => x.category));

for (let i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {

    const params = {
        term: terms[i],
        mode: 'ByInterest'
    };


    const request = this.evidenceService.get(this.job.job_id, params).map((res) => res.interactions);

    this.requests.push(request);

}

const combined = Observable.forkJoin(this.requests);

combined.subscribe((res) => {
    this.interactions = res;
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most easily chain each request with `catch` that emits just `null`:

```
const request = this.evidenceService.get(...)
  .map(...)
  .catch(error => Observable.of(null)); // Or whatever you want here
```

The failed requests will have just `null` value in the resulting array that will be emitted by `forkJoin`.

Note that you can't use `Observable.empty()` in this situation because `empty()` doesn't emit anything and just completes while `forkJoin` requires all source Observables to emit at least one value.

Comment: See "catchError" in other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50130670/745931 for the "newer" rxjs version, where you have to use pipe() instead of chaining...

Answer (score 5):

You could use rxjs [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) :

```
const request = this.evidenceService.get(this.job.job_id, params)
.pipe(map((res) => res.interactions),
catchError(error => of(undefined)));
```