# How to wait for the same observable to finish if called twice in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

My question is not the same as how to "How to wait for observable to finish". I already solved this issue in my code by using a switchMap. Currently I have an api get call that before doing the httpget, it will check if the refreshToken is expired, in this case it will generate a new token and wait for it then do the httpget which is great.

My problem is that if I have the following senario:

```
this.getUsers();
this.getLocations();
```

Let us take the case where the token needs refresh (we need to wait for the refresh):
First we call this.getUsers() this will trigger to create a new token and the get users will happen after the token is created.
In parallel we also call this.getLocations() which will also trigger to create a new token and will NOT WAIT for the first get to finish. I need to find a way so that the 2nd get waits for the 1st get to finish so that both will use the same new token.

Comment: you mean like waiting for the first request to be finish before executing the second request?

Comment: They are independent requests but if the first waits for the token to finish, the second get should also wait for it and not ask for a new token

Comment: I think what you want to do is to check first if your token expired before firing the two requests. one thing for you to avoid requesting if you token is expired is storing your token expiration time and date.

Answer (score 8):

rxjs operator for you to use in this scenario is `forkJoin()`.

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get('/app/getUser').map((res: Response) => res.json()),
    this.http.get('/app/getLocation').map((res: Response) => res.json())
).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.users = data[0]
    this.locations = data[1]
  },
  err => console.error(err)
);
```

See this Example: [Example of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38049268/1742393)

Also see this to take advantage of Observable in Angular: [Take Advantage of Observable](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html)

Comment: It's only `forkJoin(.....)` from Angular 6 onwards instead of `Observable.forkJoin(....)`

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers helped with my problem. After doing more research I was able to achieve what I want using rxjs share() which allowed multiple callers to share the same observable and hence the token gets refreshed only once.

**getUsers();** will request a refresh token then do the httpget.
**getLocation();** will detect that a refresh token is requested and hence will share the same observable and not request a new token.

Answer (score 0):

To send two request parallel and wait until both are done (code from head):

```
let [users, locations] = await Promise.all([
  this.getUsers().toPromise(),
  this.getLocations().toPromise()
]);
// `users` and `locations` are ready to use here
```

However if you wana send first request and when its finish, send second then use:

```
let users = await this.getUsers().toPromise(),
let locations= await this.getLocations().toPromise();
```

I assume that your functions `this.getUsers()` and `this.getLocations()` return angular `http.get(...)` observable (remember to put `async` keyword near function name which use above codes). More info about promises [here](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/even-with-async-await-you-probably-still-need-promises-9b259854c161).