# Error Handling - Observable.forkJoin with couple of Observable objects in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my one of the Angular application, I have two objects of types `Observable<Object1[]>` and `Observable<Object2[]>`, which call different apis in the `resolver` as below:

```
resolve(): Observable<[Array<Object1>, Array<Object2>]> {
    const object1 = this.bookingService.executeService1(); // returns Observable<Object1[]>

    const object2 = this.bookingService.executeService2(); // returns Observable<Object2[]>

    return Observable.forkJoin(object1, object2); // Need to do error handing here
}
```

It works fine unless and until the service returns an error. On error, it shows in the console as **Uncaught**. I have checked the service api through apps like postman, and it does works fine through it.

I tried to catch it as:

```
return Observable.forkJoin(object1, object2)
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error', error);
  });
```

But it doesn't help.

Let me know if there is any way to *catch the error* in the resolver through `Observable.forkJoin()`;

Answer (score 2):

You could find the answer for your concern in [the forkJoin's learnrxjs.io page](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).

> Be aware that if any of the inner observables supplied to forkJoin
>   error you will lose the value of any other observables that would or
>   have already completed if you do not catch the error correctly on the
>   inner observable. If you are only concerned with all inner observables
>   completing successfully you can catch the error on the outside.

```
const example = forkJoin(
  //emit 'Hello' immediately
  of('Hello'),
  //emit 'World' after 1 second
  of('World').pipe(delay(1000)),
  // throw error
  _throw('This will error')
).pipe(catchError(error => of(error)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as mentioned in [RxJS Angular2 handling 404 in Observable.forkjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592792/rxjs-angular2-handling-404-in-observable-forkjoin) .

Hope it will be helpful to you !

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't helped my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error in this way : 
    
    `let first = Observable.of({value : 1}); 
    let second = Observable.throw({value : 2});
    Observable.forkJoin(first, second)
              .subscribe((res: Array<any>) => console.log(res),
              (error) => {
                console.log(error);  //{value: 2} will get displayed here
              });`

You can also catch the error in each observable independently and return another observable in such cases.
    
    `return Observable.forkJoin(
        this.http.get('/url')
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch(res:Response => Observable.of({}),
        this.http.get('/url2')
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch(res:Response => Observable.of({}),
    );`

Comment: Although it logs the error, but it is still Uncaught and shows Uncaught error in the console, which shouldn't happen.